# How to read text from image in PHP

Tags: php, image, ocr, tesseract

I have downloaded repository from GIT https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php

I have below image:
[image]

And I want text like
**"The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"**

I have used below code. But it gives EMPTY result.

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';// if you are using composer
use thiagoalessio\TesseractOCR\TesseractOCR;
$result = new TesseractOCR('text.jpeg'))->run();
echo $result;
```

You can download my script using below link:
https://files.fm/u/9vecfvk9

Also you can upload working code in https://files.fm and share working code link.

Please guys help me. Your answers are appreciated.

Thank you so much in advanced!

Comment: Hi check if you have error reporting enabled.

Comment: Error reporting is enabled.

Comment: Is it necessary to install Tesseract.exe file in winnows.